# Getting info from a website using Jsoup

Tags: android, html, jsoup

So I'm making a small app for myself so I can see my earnings for my apps using Jsoup. The code I have works perfectly, it's extracting the text that I'm having trouble with. I looked at the source code for the website and the text that I want to extract is in a div class named "subheading".

```
 <div class="subheading">
    Total revenue: $1.17
       <a href="/reports?date_range=0" class="link">Reports</a>
 </div>
```

This is what the div class looks like. Now I want to extract the piece that says "Total revenue: $1.17". So in my code I put

```
Elements elements = document.select("div.subheading");
```

When I run the app, it doesn't crash, it just shows up blank. I know my code works though because I put "body" into the document.select(); and the entire body showed up. Does anyone know why nothing is showing up when I use "div.subheading"? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
Elements elements = doc.select("div.subheading");
String data = elements.text();
Log.i(".........",""+data);
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, although I just realized that the website I am trying to access data from requires a login. Do you know if there's a way to create a login screen with EditTexts using Jsoup?

Comment: @user1798956 jsoup is for parsing html tags not for creating login screen. You need to create a login screen in android and login to the website.